# How do I dynamically detect what hostname/port to connect to find a WCF service when debugging in VS

Tags: wpf, wcf

WCF service is hosted in a website in the same solution as my WPF client.

Given that the development webserver often switches ports, I was wondering if there was an easy way to detect this so I don't have to keep hardcoding / updating my config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web project properties page contains option to specify an exact port on which the development server would run. Check the 'Web' property page.

Comment: Thanks.  That is a nice simple solution.